# Generating and Solving Simultaneous ODE's in Python

Tags: python, scipy, sympy

I'm relatively new to Python, and am encountering some issues in writing a piece of code that generates and then solves a system of differential equations.

My approach to doing this was to create a set of variables and coefficients, *(x0, x1, ..., xn)* and *(c0, c1 ,..., cn)* repsectively, in a list with the function **var()**. Then the equations are constructed in **EOM1()**. The initial conditions, along with the set of equations, are all put together in **EOM2()** and solved using `odeint`.

Currently the code below runs, albeit not efficiently the reason for which I believe is because `odeint` runs through all the code with each interaction (that's something else I need to fix but isn't the main problem!).

```
import sympy as sy
from scipy.integrate import odeint

n=2
cn0list = [0.01, 0.05]
xn0list = [0.01, 0.01]

def var():
    xnlist=[]
    cnlist=[]
    for i in range(n+1):
        xnlist.append('x{0}'.format(i))
        cnlist.append('c{0}'.format(i))
    return xnlist, cnlist

def EOM1():
    drdtlist=[]
    for i in range(n):
        cn1=sy.Symbol(var()[1][i])
        xn0=sy.Symbol(var()[0][i])
        xn1=sy.Symbol(var()[0][i+1])
        eom=cn1*xn0*(1.0-xn1)-cn1*xn1-xn1
        drdtlist.append(eom)
    xi=sy.Symbol(var()[0][0])
    xf=sy.Symbol(var()[0][n])
    drdtlist[n-1]=drdtlist[n-1].subs(xf,xi)
    return drdtlist

def EOM2(xn, t, cn):
    x0, x1 = xn
    c0, c1 = cn
    f = EOM1()
    output = []
    for part in f:
        output.append(part.evalf(subs={'x0':x0, 'x1':x1, 'c0':c0, 'c1':c1}))
    return output

abserr = 1.0e-6
relerr = 1.0e-4
stoptime = 10.0
numpoints = 20

t = [stoptime * float(i) / (numpoints - 1) for i in range(numpoints)]

wsol = odeint(EOM2, xn0list, t, args=(cn0list,), atol=abserr, rtol=relerr)
```

My problem is that I had difficulty getting Python to treat the variables generated by Sympy appropriately. I got around this with the line

```
output.append(part.evalf(subs={'x0':x0, 'x1':x1, 'c0':c0, 'c1':c1}))
```

in **EOM2()**. Unfortunately, I do not know how to generalize this line to a list of variables from *x0* to *xn*, and from *c0* to *cn*. The same applies to the earlier line in **EOM2()**,

```
    x0, x1 = xn
    c0, c1 = cn
```

In other words I set *n* to an arbitrary number, is there a way for Python to interpret each element as it does with the ones I manually entered above? I have tried the following

```
output.append(part.evalf(subs={'x{0}'.format(j):var(n)[0][j], 'c{0}'.format(j):var(n)[1][j]}))
```

yet this yields the error that led me to use **evalf** in the first place,

```
TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

Is there any way do what I want to, generate a set of *n* equations which are then solved with `odeint`?

Comment: Why are you using symbols in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `evalf` you want to look into using `sympy.lambdify` to generate a callback for use with SciPy. You will need to create a function with the expected signature of `odeint`, e.g.:

```
y, params = sym.symbols('y:3'), sym.symbols('kf kb')
ydot = rhs(y, p=params)
f = sym.lambdify((y, t) + params, ydot)
yout = odeint(f, y0, tout, param_values)
```

We gave a tutorial on (among other things) how to use `lambdify` with `odeint` at the SciPy 2017 conference, the material is available here: http://www.sympy.org/scipy-2017-codegen-tutorial/

If you are open to use an external library to handle the function signatures of external solvers you may be interested in a library I've authored: [pyodesys](https://github.com/bjodah/pyodesys)

Comment: I don't think I could have asked for a more thorough and content-backed answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to make an arbitrary number of substitutions in a SymPy expression. This is how it can be done:

```
n = 10
syms = sy.symbols('x0:{}'.format(n))   # an array of n symbols
expr = sum(syms)                       # some expression with those symbols
floats = [1/(j+1) for j in range(n)]   # numbers to put in 
expr.subs({symbol: value for symbol, value in zip(syms, floats)})
```

The result of subs is a float in this case (no evalf needed).

Note that the function `symbols` can directly create any number of symbols for you, via the colon notation. No need for a loop.

Comment: Thank you, that's great! However, I am still finding some issues with odeint. In the case you provided we have a range of numbers to substitute. However in my case I cannot do this, as I want to put these equations into the odeint function, which then substitutes values into my equation. This means that I still have a problem with generating a set of equations that are compatible with odeint. Still, I am very grateful for the useful information you've provided :)